# Calling JS Function from Different File in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have an html slider call a javascript function from another file. I have this for my html:

```
    <input type="range" min="0" max="20*Math.PI" value="10" id="angularVelCarousel" onChange="changeValCarousel(this.value)"/>
    <span id="valueCarousel">10</span>
    <script src='slider.js'></script>
```

and this for my js (in a file called slider.js)

```
function changeValCarousel(value){

    document.getElementById('valueCarousel').innerHTML = value;


}
```

how can I make it so that when the slider changes, it executes the js file above?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
function changeValCarousel(value){
    document.getElementById('valueCarousel').innerHTML = value;
}

var slider = document.getElementById('angularVelCarousel');
slider.onchange=function(){changeValCarousel(slider.value)};
```

Full code here https://jsfiddle.net/ta434v5p/